# PHP Reading Directories

Tags: php, directory

So I'm going through reading and writing to files in PHP via PHP Docs and there's an example I didn't quite understand:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

if toward the end it shows an example like this:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

In what case would `.` or `..` ever be read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readdir` API call iterates over all of the directories.  So assuming you loop over the current directory (denoted by "`.`") then you get into an endless loop.  Also, iterating over the parent directory (denoted by "`..`") is avoided to restrict the list to the current directory and beneath.

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh ok, so by saying `readdir('.')` it's going to read everything - even itself? So I wouldn't run into either case if I declared a directory such as `readdir('test_directory')`

Comment: Please see @tomhallam's response.  That's the way it is in Unix filesystem.  See this for example <http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs219/CourseNotes/Unix/unix-fileStructure.html>.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read directories using PHP, I would recommend you use the `scandir` function. Below is a demonstration of scandir

```
$path = __DIR__.'/images';
$contents = scandir($path);
foreach($contents as $current){
  if($current === '.' || $current === '..') continue ;
  if(is_dir("$path/$current")){
    echo 'I am a directory';
  } elseif($path[0] == '.'){
    echo "I am a file with a name starting with dot";
  } else {
    echo 'I am a file';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in a UNIX filesystem, `.` and `..` are like signposts, as far as I know. Certainly to this PHP function, anyway.

Keep them in there, you'll get some weird results (like endless loops, etc.) otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

In *nix . is the present working directory and .. is the directory parent. However any file or directory preceded by a '.' is considered hidden so I prefer something like the following:

```
...
if ($entry[0] !== '.') {
    echo "$entry\n";
}
...
```

This ensures that you don't parse "up" the directory tree, that you don't endlessly loop the present directory, and that any hidden files/folders are ignored.

Comment: because php is a cpp based language, you can get the first character more quickly using $entry[0]